# Cygwin+tmux over ssh problems: open terminal failed: not a terminal

Tags: cygwin, tmux

I can't get `tmux` to work inside an SSH session to a Windows machine with Cygwin:

```
USER@HOST ~ $ tmux
open terminal failed: not a terminal
```

GNU/Screen is working fine. I understand `tmux` is a bit pickier, it's also much nicer to work with. Any way to get `tmux` to work?

Answer (score 1):

Due to very limited support of Windows console API in cygwin, you have to run `mintty.exe` which emulates pty terminal. However, you will lose ability to run many other Windows console applications which were not designed for cygwin, but use Windows console API directly.

Comment: `mintty` looks interesting but seems a bit buggy on my system. Inside RDP it opens but `tmux` doesn't really work (it shows up but can't do anything inside). And over SSH `mintty` doesn't do much at all.

Comment: These are cygwin limitations. Why do you want to use tmux at all?

Comment: 1. tmux is great, GNU/Screen is quite limited in comparison (and the Windows GUI over RDP is torture). 2. there are some other issues that cause trouble within Emacs and sometimes even within vi, I'm hoping this would be resolved inside tmux.

Comment: I mean, what features of tmux would you like to use? Do you run tmux on local or remote machine?

Comment: Running tmux on remote machine. I want to open multiple windows within 1 SSH session, I want to split the screen and I want to be able to reconnect a day later to things I was doing. GNU/Screen can do this but it's just not as smooth.

Answer (score 1):

You can, if you have the "screen" package installed. You can call "screen -L", from bash, before running tmux.
Or you can call it from cmd or from where you want to run the bash, bash.exe --login -c "screen -L", and after that "tmux".